# Terraform Loop through default values

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am having some issues passing some values to my variables in terraform... I am getting errors saying that a value should be expected (string or number). Here is what my code looks like:

Main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet_two_nsg" {
  name                = var.nsg_subnet_two_name != "" ? var.nsg_subnet_two_name : "${var.subnet_two_name}-NSG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.nsg_subnet_two_rules
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value["name"]
      priority                   = security_rule.value["priority"]
      direction                  = security_rule.value["direction"]
      access                     = security_rule.value["access"]
      protocol                   = security_rule.value["protocol"]
      source_port_range          = security_rule.value["source_port_range"]
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value["destination_port_range"]
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value["source_address_prefix"]
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value["destination_address_prefix"]
    }
  }
}
```

Variables.tf

```
variable "nsg_subnet_two_rules" {
  type = set(object({
    name                       = list(string) 
    priority                   = list(number)
    direction                  = string
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = list(string)
    source_port_range          = string
    destination_port_range     = list(string)
    source_address_prefix      = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
  }))
  description = "Specify the Rules for the Second Subnet. Default values follow Microsoft Best Practices"
  default = [{
    name                       = ["Allow RDP", "Allow RPC", "Allow Kerberos Passwd Exchange", "Allow RPC for LSA", "Allow LDAP", "Allow LDAP SSL", "Allow LDAP GC", "Allow LDAP GC SSL", "Allow DNS", "Allow FRS RPC", "Allow Kerberos", "Allow SMB", "Allow DFSR RPC"]
    priority                   = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = ["Tcp", "Tcp", "*", "Tcp", "*", "Tcp", "Tcp", "Tcp", "*", "Tcp", "*", "Tcp", "Tcp"]
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = ["3389", "135", "464", "49152-65535", "389", "636", "3268", "3269", "53", "49152-65535", "88", "445", "49152-65535"]
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }]
}
```

That's the error I got when I run terraform plan:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 218, in resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet_two_nsg":
│  218:       name                       = security_rule.value["name"]
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 219, in resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet_two_nsg":
│  219:       priority                   = security_rule.value["priority"]
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "priority": number required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 222, in resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet_two_nsg":
│  222:       protocol                   = security_rule.value["protocol"]
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "protocol": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 224, in resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet_two_nsg":
│  224:       destination_port_range     = security_rule.value["destination_port_range"]
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "destination_port_range": string required.
╵
```

Thanks in advance for the help and have a great night!

I've tried to change the variable to set and map, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Could you cut'n'paste the full error message into the question?

Comment: What issues exactly? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding on how variables, default values and dynamic blocks work here.

I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but you are doing it wrong.

1 - Variables exist to permit parent modules to pass values to them.

2 - Default values are used when no values are passed to the variable.

That being said, if you want to set a "constant" value for a variable, you should define it in locals {} not as default value.

3 - Dynamic blocks will loop trough a list/object/map and index it. Basically it will first look the index 0 [0], than [1] and so on.

So you need to pass a variable that can read like that.

A correct formatted variable that can be read by dynamic block would be:

```
locals {
  nsg_subnet_two_rules = [
    {
      name        = "Allow RDP"
      priority    = "100"
      direction   = "Inbound"
      ....
    },
    {
      name        = "Allow RPC"
      priority    = "101"
      direction   = "Inbound"
      ....
    },
    ....
}
```

The above variable can be access by

```
local.nsg_subnet_two_rules
```

And it can be accessed dynamically as it can be indexed like

```
local.nsg_subnet_two_rules[0]
```